# Элемент чата - пользователь пишет

Tags: php, чат

У меня есть чат. Нужно сделать скрипт типа как в Фейсбуке  "Пользователь пишет"
(сообщение).Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: слишком общий вопрос - его закроют. Нужно конкретнее спрашивать, по конкретному способу. Тут вообще тема не `php`, а `javacsript` и `ajax`

Comment: @RussCoder это касается и php, как серверного языка - потому как без сервера это не решить.  Alexey смотри в сторону websocket, для старых браузеров есть эмуляция ws на флэш

Comment: @Вадим спасибо)